Indexing CNN output grid in loss function
I have CNN model build in tensorflow which outputs grid with shape (batch_size,H,W,1).
I perform sigmoid activation function on each cell in the grid.
my y_true is tensor with [ColIndex, RowIndex, Outcome], meaning for every training instance i have exactly 1 cell with an outcome value.
I want to calculate the loss when training only for the 1 cell in the y_true, meaning I need to index the grid output to this 1 cell and calculate logloss, and use this 1 cell loss when training.
I have looked for solutions but isn't found one, i currently have managed to create a loss which the model does train but the loss are almost always 0 and i get weird results.
my loss function:
def custom_target_location_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    # Extract column indices, row indices, and values
    col_indices = tf.cast(y_true[:,0], tf.int32)  # Column indices
    row_indices = tf.cast(y_true[:,1], tf.int32)  # Row indices
    values = tf.cast(y_true[:, 2], tf.float32)     # Binary labels (0 or 1)
    
    batch_size = tf.shape(y_pred)[0]
    batch_indices = tf.range(batch_size)
    channel_indices = tf.zeros_like(batch_indices, dtype=tf.int32)
    indices = tf.stack([batch_indices,row_indices, col_indices,channel_indices], axis=1)
    
    
    y_pred_cell = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, indices)
    
    loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(values, y_pred_cell)

    # Return the mean loss across the batch
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

am i missing something here?

Your code looks fine to me. I also quickly ran it on some examples and it seems to produce expected non-zero loss values. Your problem probably relates to the rest of the model and perhaps how your problem has been framed.

Oh Great Thanks, i will tackle the model itself, i just thought the loss function was the problem because the model and the input data are implementation of a paper. again thank you
